# Unable to get a Scale`s value from a Toplevel window using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to get and print out the value of the Scale from a Toplevel window created using tkinter but only 0 s are displayed in the Python console. Here it is the code I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def window():
    newWindow = Toplevel(master)
    newWindow.geometry("400x250")
    w1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42)
    w1.pack()
    w2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    w2.pack()
    Button(master, text='Show', command=w1.get()).pack()
    Button(master, text='Show2', command=w2.get()).pack()
    print (w1.get(), w2.get())
    
btn1=Button(text="open", command=window)
btn1.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: The `w1.get()` part of `command=w1.get()` runs before you even create the button. Also the `print(w1.get(), w2.get())` runs before the user gets a chance to input values inside the `Scale`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def print_values():
    print(w1.get(), w2.get())
    # If you want to destroy the window:
    second_root.destroy()

def window():
    global w1, w2, second_root
    second_root = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_root.geometry("400x250")
    w1 = tk.Scale(second_root, from_=0, to=42)
    w1.pack()
    w2 = tk.Scale(second_root, from_=0, to=200, orient="horizontal")
    w2.pack()
    button = tk.Button(second_root, text="Click me", command=print_values)
    button.pack()
    
root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="open", command=window)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It sets the command to a function named `print_values`, which calls `.get()`. This is how event driven programming works. You tell `tkinter` to call your function whenever the user presses the button. Then you call `.get()` om the 2 `Scale`s.

Please note that I assumed that you wanted the `Scale`s and `Button` to be in the new window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the user has clicked the button or performed some other action to get the value. As written, you're getting the value immediately after creating the sliders.

This illustrates one possible way:

```
def window():
    ...
    def show():
        print(f"w1={w1.get()}")
    def show2():
        print(f"w2={w2.get()}")

    Button(master, text='Show', command=show).pack()
    Button(master, text='Show2', command=show2).pack()
```

I don't normally advocate for nesting functions like that, but it's just to show that you need to call the `get` method after the user has had a chance to interact with the sliders.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you print the value of `w1`.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
def set_value1(val):
    global w1_val
    w1_val = val
def window():
    newWindow = Toplevel(master)
    newWindow.geometry("400x250")
    w1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42, command=set_value1)
    w1.pack()
    w2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    w2.pack()
    Button(master, text='Show', command=w1.get()).pack()
    Button(master, text='Show2', command=w2.get()).pack()
    print (w1_val, w2.get())
w1_val = 0    
btn1=Button(text="open", command=window)
btn1.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I don't think it solves anything.

Comment: This seems to have exactly the same problem as the code in the question. You're fetching the result about a millisecond after creating the widget, well before the user has had a chance to interact with it.

Comment: As @TheLizzard mentioned, The `w1.get()` part of `command=w1.get()` runs before you even create the button. So in my code, I always print the value you set after your last clicking. I tested and it worked.